# Вывод полченых данных через ajax

Tags: ajax, javascript

Как вывести полученные данные от reg.php

Вот получение данных:

```
$.ajax({ url: "script/reg.php", type: "POST", data:{name: name,pass: pass}, });
```

Comment: Прочитать документацию (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? Либо конкретизировать вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script/reg.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: { name: name, pass: pass },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert(data); // Вывод данных
  }
});
```

Рекомендую почитать [официальную документацию](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), либо [документацию на русском языке](http://jquery-docs.ru/Ajax/jQuery.ajax/).